# Partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no consecutive integers in each block is counted by $B(n-1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I'm trying to understand why $B(n-1)$ also counts the number of partitions of $[n]$ where not two consecutive integers appear in the same block.

Now the bell number $B(n-1)$ counts the number of partitions of the $n-1$-set $[n-1]$. Suppose I take any partition $\pi$ of $[n-1]$. Now taking $i,i+1,\dots,j$ to be a maximal sequence of two or more consecutive integers in a block, I can remove alternating integers $j-1$, $j-3$, $j-5$,... and put them in a block with $n$. Doing so for all sequences of consecutive integers in blocks of $\pi$ will then give a partition of $[n]$ with no two consecutive numbers.

I think this gives a needed bijection of the two things, but if I'm given a partition of $[n]$ with no two consecutive integers in a block, how can I reconstruct the partition of $[n-1]$ to see that it is indeed a bijection?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, thanks for fixing the spelling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relation you give is indeed a bijection! To reconstruct the original partition of $[n-1]$, take every element $j \neq n$ in the same block as $n$ and put it in the block containing $j+1$.

Example: let's say you perform your function and arrive at the non-consecutive partition

{1,3,6}, {5}, {2,4,7}.

From your specification of how to choose which numbers to remove from the original blocks, you know that 2 was removed from a block containing 3, so put 2 back in the block {1,3,6}. Similarly, you know 4 was taken from the block containing 5, so put 4 back in the block {5}. Finally, just take out 7 entirely, and you're left with the original partition: {1,2,3,6}, {4,5}.

Comment: Ah right! Thanks for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there is an evident bijection between partitions of $\left\{0,\dots,\text{n-1}\right\}$ and length-$\text{n}$ strings on the set of characters $\left\{0,1,\dots\right\}$ with the property that the first character is $0$ and every character thereafter is at most one more than the largest character preceding it. E.g., $$\left\{0,1,4\right\}\sqcup\left\{2,5\right\}\sqcup\left\{3\right\}\ \mapsto\ \underline{0}\ \underline{0}\ \underline{1}\ \underline{2}\ \underline{0}\ \underline{1}\text{.}$$ (I.e., the $\text{k}^{\text{th}}$ character of the string, indexing from $0$, is the index of $\text{k}$'s part when the parts of the partition are ordered by their lowest members.)

There is likewise an evident bijection between partitions of $\left\{0,\dots,\text{n-1}\right\}$ in which no two consecutive elements occur in the same part and length-$\text{n}$ strings on the set of characters $\left\{*\right\}\sqcup\left\{0,1,\dots\right\}$ with the property that the first two characters are $0$ and every character thereafter is at most one more than the largest character preceding it. E.g., $$\left\{0,2,5\right\}\sqcup\left\{1\right\}\sqcup\left\{3,6\right\}\sqcup\left\{4\right\}\ \mapsto\ \underline{0}\ \underline{0}\ \underline{0}\ \underline{1}\ \underline{2}\ \underline{0}\ \underline{1}\text{.}$$ (I.e., the $\left(\text{k}+1\right)^{\text{st}}$ character of the string, indexing from $0$, is the index of $\left(\text{k}+1\right)$'s part when the parts of the partition are ordered by their lowest members and $\text{k}$'s part is omitted.)

The claim follows.